# Detail view unique to each table cell using Core Data

Tags: xcode, uitableview, detailview

So I have created a Core Data application where the user enters information on a Modal View and once "Save" is pressed, it creates a cell (or adds an item to an array) in a table. Each cell pushes to a detail view where statistics can be added for each cell. My question is, how do I ensure that each detail view is unique to each item in the table, and ensure that the stats in the detail view are saved with each corresponding cell (or array item)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Your detail view should be a generic, reusable object, that is passed the specific core data object when you initialise it.

When you select the cell, you will have its index path. The index path can be used to get the managed object, which is then passed to your detail view.

The detail view(controller) then makes any amendments to the passed in object.

This is covered in any master-detail tutorial you would find.

Comment: I've kind of accomplished this already in the sense that when the cell is pressed it passes the label from the cell to the detail view. I didn't expect it to automatically save any accompanying information information (such as information entered in a text field). I guess what I'm asking is what is the best method to use to save such information or DOES it do it automatically?

Comment: Your detail view has to update the model, this will be in code that you write. Typically this would be in text field delegate methods or similar.

Comment: Ok. My mistake is that I tried to pass the information with a pushSegue like Apple does in their master detail template. Thanks